# Python `shapely` - split a complex line at self-intersections

Tags: python, shapely, splitting, self-intersection

## Description

### Sum-up

When splitting a complex line - let's say with a single "loop" - `shapely.ops.split` applied at the self-intersection point returns two lines where I would expect three lines.
If not wrong, this is at least arbitrary in choosing the line to be actually split.

Am I missing something or is it a wrong behavior of `shapely`? I didn't find any tickets for that matter in [github](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+split).
If I didn't make any obvious mistake, I'll open one.

### Details and code

Using a simple example of a line crossing itself once:
[image: Complex line basic example]

```py
from shapely import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import split

# Simple self-crossing line
a = Point((1, 0))
e = Point((0, 1))
b = Point((1, 2))
c = Point((2, 2))
d = Point((2, 1))
ae = LineString([a, b, c, d, e])

# Intersection point
# note: this can be extracted, see below
x = Point((1, 1))

# This splits the line in two, not in three as I would expect
ae_split = split(ae, x)
```

This splits the line into two (to some extend arbitrary chosen) lines:

[image]

Where I would expect it to be split in three:

[image]

Note that the self-intersection points can be found using a workaround (from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423351/identifying-self-intersections-in-linestring-using-shapely)): extract the duplicated points after a `unary_union`.

```py
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint
from collections import Counter

def find_self_intersection(line):
    intersection = None
    if not line.is_simple:
        intersection = unary_union(line)
        seg_coordinates = []
        for seg in intersection.geoms:
            seg_coordinates.extend(list(seg.coords))
        intersection = [Point(p) for p, c in Counter(seg_coordinates).items() if c > 1]
        intersection = MultiPoint(intersection)
    return intersection
```

## Workaround

For now, the only workaround I found is to use `difference` before splitting.
I don't know how robust this is, and any suggestion is welcome.

```py
# This returns a MultiLineString (with three elements)
ae_diff = ae.difference(x)

# This returns a GeometryCollection of (three) LineString
ae_split = split(ae.difference(x), x)
```

Comment: Just thinking out aloud, may be the split function was never designed to split at a self-intersecting location? I say this as you don't know if that self intersection is passing over or under itself? This is why you are getting those arbitrary results? That's my guess.

Comment: @Hornbydd Hum here by construction, the segment `ab` would be "below" the segment `de`, and the former is chosen to be split. I don't know if it would always be that way, I can quickly try to construct the complex line in a different order. But anyway it remains arbitrary.

Comment: Your intuition is right: constructing the line in the reverse order `ea = LineString([e, d, c, b, a])` changes the split (the segment 'ed' is split). There is a pattern in the arbitrariness of the split, even though I'm pretty sure you shouldn't rely on it...

Comment: I think that's what I'm getting at that, you may not known which order the lines cross and the algorithm behind the split function resolves this in an arbitrary way. I've experienced arbitrariness in code and its down to the row order in tables. e.g. you created lines 1,2,3 and I created lines 3,2,1 but we both seen all lines. The algorithm then probably resolves on a first come first served basis? Well something like that.

Comment: Looking into it, it does work on a first-intersection-along-the-line basis.

Here's the source: https://github.com/shapely/shapely/blob/1.8.2/shapely/ops.py#L456-L499 - shapely finds the projection of the point along the linestring, and loops over the coordinates on the linestring until it reaches that splitting point, splits and returns.. so there's no further checking of the rest of the line for the case where the point would split it again, somewhere further along.

Comment: In GEOS, which is where the call to `line.project(splitter)` ends up, the API docs and source agree - if more than one point along the line has the closest distance, the first on is returned [src](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/main/src/linearref/LengthIndexedLine.cpp#L112-L116), [API docs](https://libgeos.org/doxygen/classgeos_1_1linearref_1_1LengthIndexedLine.html#a73f71dc4e3956f4fcc9a98e732f155a2) - generateed from the corresponding [header file](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/main/include/geos/linearref/LengthIndexedLine.h).

Comment: Interesting that GEOS provides [`indexOfAfter`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/e3abcc8fc0f60035c7d8bda65e2417873f6da872/src/linearref/LengthIndexOfPoint.cpp#L61) to check for further line intersections. Calling [`indexOfFromStart`](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/e3abcc8fc0f60035c7d8bda65e2417873f6da872/src/linearref/LengthIndexOfPoint.cpp#L85) which walks over the segments in the line in a loop. Once we've found an intersection point at `minDistance` presumably 0, any later points will be ignored, so `minIndex` lets the call skip forward to a point and start checking from there.

Comment: @tlrss Thank you for your detailed comments. Then OK this is what is expected from the source, but should it be that way splitting a line with a self-intersecting point? Following your hints, I'll read the source and I think it makes sense to open a `shapely`/`geos` issue.